# Why are some of the values of items' fields repeating in this Scrapy spider?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

When my spider runs on a url like [this](http://211sepa.org/get-help/housing/):

```
def parse_subandtaxonomy(self, response):
item = response.meta['item']
for sub in response.xpath('//div[@class = "page-content"]/section'):
    item['Subcategory'] = sub.xpath('h2/text()').extract()
    for tax in sub.xpath('ul/li/a'):
        item['Taxonomy'] = tax.xpath('text()').extract()
        for href in tax.xpath('@href'):
            # url = response.urljoin(href.extract()) - > this gave me 301 redirects
            badurl = urljoin('https://211sepa.org/search/', href.extract())
            url = badurl.replace('search?', 'search/?area_served=Philadelphia&', 1) # shut off to test multi-page
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_listings)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield item
```

I recieve this output, which is what I expect:

```
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Affordable Housing"], "Taxonomy": ["Section 8 Vouchers"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Affordable Housing"], "Taxonomy": ["Public Housing"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Affordable Housing"], "Taxonomy": ["Low Income/ Subsidized Rental Housing"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Shelter"], "Taxonomy": ["Homeless Shelters"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Shelter"], "Taxonomy": ["Homeless Shelter Centralized Intake"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Shelter"], "Taxonomy": ["Domestic Violence Shelters"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Shelter"], "Taxonomy": ["Runaway/ Youth Shelters"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Shelter"], "Taxonomy": ["Cold Weather Shelters/ Warming Centers"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Shelter"], "Taxonomy": ["Homeless Shelter for Pregnant Women"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Stay Housed"], "Taxonomy": ["Rent Payment Assistance"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Stay Housed"], "Taxonomy": ["Mortgage Payment Assistance"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Stay Housed"], "Taxonomy": ["Landlord/ Tenant Mediation"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Stay Housed"], "Taxonomy": ["General Dispute Mediation"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Overcome Homelessness"], "Taxonomy": ["Transitional Housing/ Shelter"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Overcome Homelessness"], "Taxonomy": ["Rental Deposit Assistance"]}
{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Overcome Homelessness"], "Taxonomy": ["Permanent Supportive Housing"]}
```

but then when I change `yield item` to `yield request` to continue on in the crawl, each item has `{"Category": ["Housing"], "Subcategory": ["Overcome Homelessness"], "Taxonomy": ["Permanent Supportive Housing"] ... other item info ... }` instead of its respective subcategory and taxonomy. Each item that I eventually want from each taxonomy is scraped, but it's incorrectly labeled as described above. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an issue with scopes. You should always try to create your item on the highest scope possible to prevent data retention, i.e. if the current `item` doesn't have `Taxonomy` field, the object will retain data from the previous loop cycle. That's why the code should have create new object in every loop cycle when possible.

Try this:

```
def parse_subandtaxonomy(self, response):
    for sub in response.xpath('//div[@class = "page-content"]/section'):
        subcategory = sub.xpath('h2/text()').extract()
        subcategory = sub.xpath('h2/text()').extract_first()  # this just takes first element which is nicer!
        for tax in sub.xpath('ul/li/a'):
            item = response.meta['item'].copy()
            item['Subcategory'] = subcategory
            item['Taxonomy'] = tax.xpath('text()').extract()
            for href in tax.xpath('@href'):
                # url = response.urljoin(href.extract()) - > this gave me 301 redirects
                badurl = urljoin('https://211sepa.org/search/', href.extract())
                url = badurl.replace('search?', 'search/?area_served=Philadelphia&', 1) # shut off to test multi-page
                request = scrapy.Request(url, 
                                         callback=self.parse_listings,
                                         meta={'item': item})  # you can put meta here directly
                yield request
```

Comment: This did it and makes sense, thanks.

Also curious why you used `item = response.meta['item'].copy()` instead of just `item = response.meta['item']`

Comment: @g_raham to create new, clean item object for every loop cycle, to prevent data retention from previous loop cycles. Scrapy Item is pretty much a python dictionary and you can in fact use python dictionary instead of Item.